# Convert range formatted as date to text

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have range of cells in date format, formatted as `dd.mm.yyyy`, like this:

```
05.10.1993
05.10.1993
05.10.1993
05.10.1993
```

and I want to convert this range of cells to text format, using VBA, but without iterating each cell in range (as it is slow for large range).

I used this code:

```
Set rSel = Selection

aDate = rSel.Value
rSel.NumberFormat = "@"
rSel.Value = aDate
```

So I assign selected range to intermediate array, then convert the range to text format and assign the array back to selected range.

Result is this text:

```
5/10/1993
5/10/1993
5/10/1993
5/10/1993
```

and I wonder where did format conversion took place, as if I `debug.print` for example `aDate(1,1)` I get expected `05.10.1993` value? Or how can I instruct format in simple snippet I posted so that I get expected text as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, instead of `aDate=rSel.Value`, try this:

```
aDate = Application.Text(rSel.Value2,rSel.NumberFormatLocal)
```

*Note*

The following range properties are relevant to this example:

`.Value` returns a variant (number/date/string/boolean/error) with dates in VBA date format.

`.Value2` returns a variant (number/string/boolean/error) with dates converted to serial numbers.

`.Text` returns a string containing the formatted value, this applies to individual cells only.

`.NumberFormat` returns regional formats in US format (eg entering 1/2/3 in a cell gives *m/d/yyyy*)

`.NumberFormatLocal` returns regional formats in local format (eg in European locale *d/m/yy*)

Comment: I don't see `Application.Text` method available in my Excel 2010

Comment: True, but you should see `Application.WorksheetFunction.Text`. The difference is `Application.Text` returns a variant so allows for arrays and errors in outputs. This applies to all other worksheetfunction methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that I [posted on my blog](http://yoursumbuddy.com/copy-numbers-with-formatting-to-strings/). It uses a loop in one direction, but should be a lot faster than your loop attempts. It uses a trick of `Selecting` a new cell every so often, to account for this [bug described by Charles Williams](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/).

```
Sub NumberToStringWithFormat(rng As Excel.Range)
Dim Texts() As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

'This might prevent "###" if column too narrow
rng.EntireColumn.AutoFit
'Can't use variables in Dim
ReDim Texts(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To rng.Columns.Count)
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    'Charles Williams' fix for slow code with Text
   If i Mod 1000 = 0 Then
        rng.Range("A1").Offset(i).Select
    End If
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        Texts(i, j) = rng.Cells(i, j).Text
    Next j
Next i
'@ is the Text format
rng.NumberFormat = "@"
rng.Value2 = Texts
End Sub
```